# Image Migration from Drupal 6 to 7 fails

Tags: migrations

Happy New Year everyone,

I am fairly new to the Migrate Module and have come to a halt concerning image migration. To begin with, my problem currently is that when I run my migration, drush outputs: "New object was not saved, no error provided".

Now all I want is to get the images relating to a specific content type (educational_activity) and copy them over to my destination folder.

CODE:

```
class EduActFile extends EduMigration {

public function __construct() {

parent::__construct();

#Define variable for the default user id (user="grammateia") wherever it is used (uid, revision_uid, etc.). 
$user=36;

// Describe the class for the Migrate UI

$this->description = t('Migrate files');



$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'migrationDB')
           ->select('node', 'n');
//$query->leftJoin('content_field_filename', 'fi', 'n.nid = fi.nid');
$query->leftJoin('content_field_images', 'fim', 'n.nid = fim.nid');
//$query->leftJoin('files', 'fil', 'fil.fid = fi.field_filename_fid');
$query->leftJoin('files', 'file', 'file.fid = fim.field_images_fid');
$query->fields('n')
      //->fields('fil', array('fid', 'filename', 'filepath', 'filemime', 'filesize', 'timestamp'))
      ->fields('file', array('fid', 'filename', 'filepath', 'filemime', 'filesize', 'timestamp'))
      ->condition('type', "educational_activity",'=')
      ->groupBy('n.nid');


$this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, array(), NULL, array('map_joinable' => FALSE));

// Specify that we want to create files from the source data

$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('');

// Remember what source record created each destination object and track migration status and allow rollback with MigrateSQLMap class

$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
    array(
      'nid' => array('type' => 'int',
                       'not null' => TRUE,
                       'description' => 'Node ID',
                       'alias' => 'n'
                      )
    ),
  MigrateDestinationFile::getKeySchema()
);

$this->addUnmigratedSources(array ('fid','filepath', 'filemime', 'filesize', 'timestamp'), t('Source fields that we will not be migrating'));

$this->addUnmigratedDestinations (array('timestamp', 'destination_file'));

$this->addFieldMapping('uid')
  ->defaultValue($user);

// For each source row to be processed define data mappings to the destination field from source field

$this->addFieldMapping('value', 'filename');


// Specify the location of the source folder to find the files

$this->addFieldMapping('source_dir')
     ->defaultValue('C:/xampp/htdocs/protovoulia.org/sites/default/files');

// Specify the location of the destination folder to place the files

$this->addFieldMapping('destination_dir')
     ->defaultValue('C:/xampp/htdocs/testpaideia/sites/default/files/educational_activity');


// Use existing files

$this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')->defaultValue('FILE_EXISTS_REUSE');

// Ensure files are not deleted during rollback

$this->addFieldMapping('preserve_files')->defaultValue(TRUE);

}//construct ends
```

}

Do I need to use a different class to migrate files? Is my query wrong? Thanks in advance, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything helpful in watchdog?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the watchdog logs regarding this migration only contain the generic error  "New object was not saved, no error provided".

I figured though that the image files that are assigned to the node instances I am checking have an fid value of "NULL" in the "content_field_images" table. I am guessing that is the culprit.

Comment: How about going to admin/content/migrate and seeing if the "messages" column has a link for that migration? I had the exact same problem yesterday and the messages page for that migration had more details about what was wrong (permissions issue in my case).

Comment: I will investigate the permissions issue as soon as I have time thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered by me in another question I made. 
It can be found here: [Migrating Multiple Files in a Node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/migrating-multiple-files-in-a-node)